# MCU 8051 IDE with SDCC stuck at compiling

Tags: c, embedded, sdcc, mcu

I am a student and have been instructed by the college to use MCU 8051 IDE with SDCC for learning microcontroller programming. I installed this software successfully on many HP devices in college but when I am trying to use it on my home Dell Inspiron 15 3000 laptop following happens:

[image: SDCC is Stuck Compiling]

```
Starting compiler ...

cd "E:\\Embedded Systems Practical"
sdcc -mmcs51 --iram-size 256 --xram-size 0 --code-size 8192  --nooverlay --noinduction --verbose --debug -V --std-sdcc89 --model-small   "prac4.c"
```

The IDE gets stuck here. Even after aborting the IDE freezes and needs to be restarted. I tried multiple fresh installs on my PC but nothing works.

I brought a pre-compiled version from the college PC to verify that the error is with SDCC and the simulation works perfectly fine.

Can someone help me how to resolve the unknown error?

Comment: Did you try to use the command line with the very same command? What happens then? We need to find out which program hangs, the IDE or the compiler. -- You might want to try the option `-v` to get some more verbose output, I expect this should work. -- On the other working machines, do the paths have spaces in their name? Did you try a directory without spaces?

Comment: It seems to be `-V` (upper case) or `--verbose` for SDCC.

Comment: As you point out, the IDE freezes, not necessarily the compiler.  Try executing that same command from the shell (cmd or powershell) so you can determine if it is the compiler or the IDE at fault. If the SDCC command works, I suggest you try reinstall Code:: Blocks, check you have the most recent version, (perhaps try an older version if you do), and/or run the Windows compatibility wizard on it.  Even try running it "as admin".  These are all Windows troubleshooting procedures, so off-topic on SO since it is an issue with your development host, not your code.

Comment: @thebusybee I tried the command line, which works perfectly fine. It created all the dependencies too. As also asked, I tried the possibility of a file path having spaces in the name be the problem which turned out to be incorrect resulting in the same freezing of MCU IDE.

Comment: @Clifford as pointed command line works fine. I tried all your troubleshooting advice but non helped to resolve the problem.

Comment: You can try to "replace" SDCC with some dummy application, and experiment with that, just to find out _what_ makes the IDE freeze. Whether this helps in the end, is unknown. Anyway, if this is a bug in Code::Blocks, you might want to report it at its project.